# WebClient + SSL exception with Android 4 and Mono for Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, webclient, xamarin

I'm using MfA 4.2.5, and whenever I use System.Net.WebClient to download a string from a SSL URL, I get an error pertaining to the certificate. The certificate appears to be valid, and I get the error on Android 4.0.3 but no error with Android 2.3.

Here's the exception: System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a

and here's the URL: https://cws.auburn.edu/map/api/2.0/Building

Comment: Can you try your code by adding this line `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (p1, p2, p3, p4) => true;` ?

Comment: That gets me on the right trail.  Can you put this in an answer, so I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in 4.2.5.  The suggested workaround until the next version is in this bug report under comment #7

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6501